# Drawing a circle with a shader in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, glsl, shader

I am trying to draw a centered circle to fill in image with a shader in SpriteKit using Swift. I am using this link to learn about shaders, and the section I'm using for this looks like this:

```
vec2 center = vec2(uResolution.x/2., uResolution.y/2.);

float radius = uResolution.x/2.;

vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy - center;

if (length(position) > radius) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.), 1.);
} else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.), 1.);
}
```

But I wanted to use this with SpriteKit so I rewrote it as this:

```
void main() {

    vec2 center = u_sprite_size / 2.0;
    float radius = center.x;
    vec2 position = v_tex_coord - center;

    if (length(position) > radius) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.0), 1.0);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), 1.0);
    }

}
```

This is how I am loading the shader:

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "napolean.png")
node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
node.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "circle.fsh")
addChild(node)
```

When I run the image is always black, and `gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), 1.0);` is never run, and there are no errors in the console. Could someone explain what is going wrong? Thanks

**Update**

[Okapi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4233369/okapi) pointed out that u_tex_coord is normalized, so I normalized the center then divided it in half like this:  `vec2 center = (u_sprite_size) / length(u_sprite_size) / 2.0;`. After I do that I can the the circle, but it is too small and off center

Comment: I think `v_tex_coord` is in unit coordinates `[0-1]` so centre should be `vec2(0.5,0.5)` and radius should be `1.0`

Comment: Ok, I just tried that and now the whole screen is white instead of black.

Comment: Oh wait, If I normalize u_sprite_size like this: `center = (u_sprite_size / 2.0) / length(u_sprite_size / 2.0);` then I can see the circle is working, but its too big and off center.

Comment: Actually I think `vec2 center = (u_sprite_size) / length(u_sprite_size) / 2.0;` would normalize it, then get half, but its to small and off center when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since `v_tex_coord` is normalized, you don’t have to use `u_sprite_size` at all—the texture coordinate will always be in the (0,0)–(1,1) range, which means your center and radius are always (0.5, 0.5) and 0.5 respectively. Your shader code can just be this:

```
void main() {
    const float radius = 0.5;
    vec2 position = v_tex_coord - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

    if (length(position) > radius) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.0), 1.0);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), 1.0);
    }
}
```